# PHP JSON Extension

Tags: php, json, php-5.4, php-5.5

I have already seen posts mentioning this on StackOverflow, but there is something I'm not understanding.

The `json` module for php is installed using `apt-get install php5-json`. I read from the PHP site that the `json` extension is no longer supported as of PHP 5.4, due to a license conflict or something like that.

Is it still safe or good to use an old extension like `php5-json`?

Comment: Isn't JSON default build in PHP? See: http://php.net/manual/en/json.installation.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a working `php5-json` module shipped with all versions of PHP. In PHP7, however, the underlying code is [replaced with](https://liorkaplan.wordpress.com/2015/03/13/php7-replaces-non-free-json-extension/) code from the `jsond` extension, which has resulted in some noticeable changes related to more strict compliance with the [JSON RFC](http://rfc7159.net/).

Now, *Debian* [replaced the non-free JSON extension](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=692613) in *PHP 5.5* with a free implementation, and I'm not sure if it's even the same free implementation (`jsond`) used in PHP 7.0. So, in short, you may notice differences between these various implementations in how they handle non-strict JSON, but, all versions of PHP are shipping with a `json` extension that is API-compatible. If you're using strict, compliant JSON, you'll never notice a thing!